# Best way to terminate a wizard in android

Tags: android, ipc, wizard, android-intent

I have a reservation wizard in android, when i say wizard i mean i have multiple activities (meaning screens) that are passed from one to another until booking is complete. in each step of the way my info may be invalid and so ill have to back track 2-3 activities and start all over, all the activities i back tracked should be destroyed, they may need to invalidate a singleton data container that they filled with their data.
I thought of 2 ways to do this:

1. start all activities related to the wizard with `startActivityForResult()` so i get notification when an activity is finished and with which error code (finished OK or error occurred) and act accordingly (for instance: if in the middle an activity fails it will return failed and the previous one will return failed as well until i get to the wizard's first activity where i either declare the error with a dialog or show the 'thank you' screen.)
2. I can send an react on intents with certain parameters so i have a 'close and clean' intent message that close down the previous activity etc...

which way is better, any other interesting\efficient way to do this ?

Comment: Shouldn't you validate what's on each activity BEFORE moving on to the next activity?  And if you only know if a previous screen is invalid after leaving it, make it an error on the activity that realizes it.  They can either fix it on that activity or click a Back button that you provide.

Comment: "I have a reservation wizard in android, when i say wizard i mean i have multiple activities (meaning screens) that are passed from one to another until booking is complete." -- consider using a single activity here, with a `ViewFlipper` or something to move between wizard steps.

Comment: colithium: i should and i do :-) but that's the thing with web services that everyone can use unless you check every step of the way you can't be 100% sure you still have what you were looking for (especially when it comes to vacations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got a hint that got me thinking in a different direction:

1. use an invisible Activity, or alternatively , a local service,that is the 'brains' that known on each turn of the way what action is to be taken. to remove a complete stack of unneeded activities i should use the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP on the  bottom most activity i want to use next.
2. Another options is to enclose all
   the activities i want to play with
   their pposition on the stack inside
   an ActivityGroup Object which keeps
   all activities alive (like in Tab)
   and on the stack, but you control
   which one is displayed and which is
   not. the activity group will contain
   the state machine logic regarding
   which Actvity should not be
   displayed and which should be
   disposed.